Deployment of Google Functions set to europe-west1 can't find tags-list
I want to deploy Google Functions (using Firebase as platform). Even though I set the region on the function itself and in the firebase.json. So I am sure it deploys only on europe-west1. But still I get this error when deploying:

Failed docker command with error  Request to https://eu.gcr.io/v2/my-app/gcf/europe-west1/tags/list had HTTP Error: 404, Not Found {"name":"FirebaseError","chil
dren":[],"context":{"body":{"errors":[{"code":"NAME_UNKNOWN","message":"Repository "eu.gcr.io" not found"}],"error":{"message":"Not Found"}},"response":{"statusCode":404}},"exit":1,"message":"Request to https://eu.gcr.io/v2/my-app/gcf/europe-west1/tags/list had HTTP Error: 404, Not Found","status":404}

This is the command: firebase deploy --only functions:myFunction --debug
What could be some hickups which lead to this behaviour? Maybe I am missing something in the configuration to set this up properly.
Update:
I followed these instructions: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4757#issuecomment-2356347800
So the tags list can be found. Now I got a new errors when deploying with firebase:
Could not find image for function projects/my-app/locations/europe-west1/functions/myFunction
and
{"error":{"code":404,"message":"Package \"projects/my-app/locations/europe-west1/repositories/gcf-artifacts/packages/myFunction\" was not found.","status":"NOT_FOUND"}}
In the Artifact Registry, there are now four *.gcr.io repositories with no artifacts in them, and fifth one named "gcf-artifacts" which is always created when I deploy my functions. There are also artifacts for my functions with images in all of them.
Regarding the error message, I don't understand why it is not finding any of the images or the function.
Side note: The artifacts have strange names, for example "my--app__europe--west1__myFunction". Maybe that's why the myFunction is "not found".
Any ideas?
